# Why wont my function clean my values

Tags: php

I am getting a value called subtotal from another page. I want to clean the value. But it wont work. It is not returning any value.

```
if (isset($_GET['subtotal'])) 
{
    $sub =  htmlentities($_GET['subtotal']);
    echo cleanData($sub);

}

function cleanData($data)
{
    $data=trim();
    $data=stripcslashes();
    $data=htmlspecialchars();
    $data=strip_tags();
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: you must give the `$data` as parameter to the functions

Comment: it should be like `htmlspecialchars(stripcslashes(trim($data)))`

Comment: `$data=trim();` - what do you think this line does?

Comment: @Seer, why not make your comment an answer, so that it can be upvoted and approved by the OP?

Comment: Beware of trying to magically "clean" data by calling all the possible "cleaning" functions you can think of. Calling `htmlentities` followed by `htmlspecialchars` and/or `strip_tags` is unlikely to do what you want; you'll end up with HTML entities like `&gt;` being displayed on the page. An I have no idea why you think you need `stripcslashes`.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to set `$data` as functions parameter. Thats why you get empty string - `trim`,  `stripcslashes`, `htmlspecialchars`, `strip_tags` will return empty string when parameter is empty too.

```
function cleanData($data)
    {
        $data=trim($data);
        $data=stripcslashes(data);
        $data=htmlspecialchars(data);
        $data=strip_tags(data);
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you must set $data as functions parameter

use this

```
if (isset($_GET['subtotal'])) 
{
    $sub =  htmlentities($_GET['subtotal']);
    echo cleanData($sub);

}

function cleanData($data)
{
    return strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(stripcslashes(trim($data))));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// pass $data to the functions
if (isset($_GET['subtotal'])) 
{
   $sub =  htmlentities($_GET['subtotal']);
   echo cleanData($sub);

}

function cleanData($data)
{
   $data=trim($data);
   $data=stripcslashes($data);
   $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
   $data=strip_tags($data);
   return $data;
}
```